# Numpy Array - Advanced slicing using sum of a one hot encoded column

Tags: arrays, numpy, sum, slice

I'm trying to slice an array based on a one-hot encoded column, so for an array like this:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[0.1,1,0,0],[0.2,1,0,0],[0.3,1,0,0]])
```

I would like to select from the first column, any rows before the cumulative sum of column 2 equals 3:

```
output = arr[0:2,0]
```

Is there any way of doing this without looping to create the cumulative sum of column 2?

Answer (score 0):

`np.cumsum` works to create the cumulative sum column without looping... oops